# Google app script - looping through the rows in a spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to loop through rows within a spreadsheet and identify if a particular row has the key word "hello" and move that entire row into a new spreadsheet.

I have attempted the following code. The code works for the first row but doesn't loop through and stops after the first row. Expanding the range selection to "C1:E32" does not help.

```js
function Edit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activatedSheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var ActiveSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ActiveSheet"); // source sheet
  var MoveDatatoThisSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MoveDatatoThisSheet"); //    target sheet
  var re = new RegExp(/(Hello)/i);
  var startRow = 1;
  var endRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var getRange = ss.getDataRange();
  var getRow = getRange.getRow();

  for (var ree = startRow; ree <= endRow; ree++) {
    // if the value in column D is "Approved", move the row to target sheet
    cellValue = ss.getRange("C1:E1");
    if (cellValue.getValue().match(re)) {
      // insert a new row at the second row of the target sheet
      MoveDatatoThisSheet.insertRows(2, 1);
      // move the entire source row to the second row of target sheet
      var rangeToMove = ActiveSheet.getRange(/*startRow*/ getRow, /*startColumn*/ 1, /*numRows*/ 1, /*numColumns*/ ActiveSheet.getMaxColumns());
      rangeToMove.moveTo(MoveDatatoThisSheet.getRange("A2"));
      // add date and time of when approved to target row in column E
      MoveDatatoThisSheet.getRange("E2").setValue(Date());
      // delete row from source sheet
      ActiveSheet.deleteRow(cellValue, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a specific add-on for that. **Just Move It** https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/just-move-it/femjblkhjnmfgldgimcbaaogkbfiiobl?utm_source=permalink

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your loop never uses the variable `ree`, it only operates with `cellValue = ss.getRange("C1:E1")`.

Another problem is that deletion shifts the rows under the deleted one, possibly causing subsequent operations to act on a wrong row. When you go through an array of rows, deleting some of them, do it bottom up, not top down.

```
for (var ree = endRow; ree >= startRow; ree--) {   
  var rangeToCheck = ss.getRange(ree, 3, 1, 3); // 3 columns starting with column 3, so C-E range 
  if (rangeToCheck.getValues()[0].join().match(re)) {   // joining values before checking the expression
    MoveDatatoThisSheet.insertRows(2,1);
    var rangeToMove = ActiveSheet.getRange(/*startRow*/ getRow, /*startColumn*/ 1, /*numRows*/ 1, /*numColumns*/ ActiveSheet.getMaxColumns());
    rangeToMove.moveTo(MoveDatatoThisSheet.getRange("A2"));
    // add date and time of when approved to target row in column E
    MoveDatatoThisSheet.getRange("E2").setValue(Date());
    // delete row from source sheet
    ActiveSheet.deleteRow(ree);
  }
}
```

If the goal is to check only column D (say), the code simplifies slightly

```
  var rangeToCheck = ss.getRange(ree, 4); //  column D in row ree
  if (rangeToCheck.getValue().match(re)) {   // joining values before checking the expression
```

#### Performance

As [Google recommends](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices),  one should avoid multiple calls to getValues / setValues and such, instead grabbing all necessary data at once, processing it, and making batch changes at once. E.g., instead of placing it a row in another sheet, add it to an array; when the loop ends, place the entire array in that sheet.

Comment: You should note that this approach is liklely to be very slow for any signifcant number of rows because you are making calls to the spreadsheet service in every iteration of the loop.